# AJAX call prevents navigating to other pages until it has finished

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here's the flow for my HTML5 dashboard page that displays several Google Charts asynchronously.

1. Asynchronous AJAX calls are made for each chart to retrieve data.
2. AJAX calls invoke PHP files.
3. PHP files retrieve data from Oracle database.
4. As data for each chart is retrieved, the respective chart is rendered.

It's a pretty cool dashboard :-)

Here comes the problem:  When I click on another hyperlink on the same page (such as a link to the Settings page), the browser's progress icon spins and it doesn't navigate to the new page until all charts complete loading.

I thought that making "asynchronous" calls allows you to leave a page. I would like to navigate away from the charts page even if all the charts haven't completed loading.

I am using Microsoft IIS as the web server and PHP 7.4.

Here's my code for making the AJAX call.

```
function drawChart(chartType, chartDivName, dataFileName, dataFileParam1, dataFileParam2) {
    var chartDiv = document.getElementById(chartDivName);

    // first, display the loading message
    chartDiv.innerHTML = "<img class='img-fluid' src='/images/loading.gif' alt='Loading...'>";

    // get the data asynchronously
    $.ajax({
        url         : dataFileName,
        method      : "POST",
        data        : {param1: dataFileParam1, param2: dataFileParam2},
        dataType    : "JSON",
        async       : true,
        success     : function(data) {
            displayChart (chartDiv, data);
        },
        error       : function(xhr, status, error) {
               chartDiv.innerHTML = "show the error";
        }
    });

} // end drawChart
```

This is how I invoke the above function:

```
<!-- Load charts -->
<script>
    // set the reportDate variable and the report-date form field
    reportDate = getYesterdayDate();
    $('#report-date').val(reportDate);

    /*
    **
    ** Place all charts and dynamic data calls that need to be loaded on the pgae in this function.
    ** This function should include the call to loading the daily charts.
    **
    */
    function loadAllCharts() {
        //load daily charts and dynamic data
        loadDailyCharts();

        // load non-daily charts and dynamic data
        getHtmlData("mtd-order-total", '/om/data/mtd_om_total.php', '', '');
        getHtmlData("mtd-ar-total", '/ar/data/mtd_ar_total.php', '', '');
        drawChart('column', 'monthly-orders-chart', '/om/chart-data/monthly_om_totals.php', '', '');
        drawChart('column', 'monthly-ar-chart', '/ar/chart-data/monthly_ar_totals.php', '', '');
    }

    /*
    **
    ** Place all charts and dynamic data calls that need to be refreshed when the date field is changed
    ** in this function.
    **
    */
    function loadDailyCharts() {
        //load dynamic data
        getHtmlData("yday-order-total", '/om/data/daily_om_total.php', reportDate, '');
        getHtmlData("yday-ar-total", '/ar/data/daily_ar_total.php', reportDate, '');

        // load charts
        drawChart('single-column', 'day-orders-chart', '/om/chart-data/daily_om_by_source.php', reportDate, '')
        drawChart('single-column', 'day-ar-chart', '/ar/chart-data/daily_ar_by_type.php', reportDate, '');
    }


    // Load all charts on page load
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(loadAllCharts);


    // Reload charts when report-date is changed
    $('#refresh-report').click(function() {
        reportDate = $("#report-date").val();
        loadDailyCharts();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your .ajax calls being made from the $(document).ready jquery function? AJAX calls made in that context might block the window.load() event which is fired off after initial Javascript execution. Try using window.load() instead of document.ready().

FYI -- This is just my best guess. I could make a better guess if you could share your html with me as well as the Javascript around your function's invocation.

Comment: Hi Jibreel, I revised my post with the full javascript in the HTML that is loading the Google Charts.  I use "google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(loadAllCharts);" to load the charts.  Can you please check my code and comment?

Comment: Alright, my next guess is to look at "getHTMLData()". What are those functions? Are they GETs? Are they synchronous GETs?

If your getHTML functions are behaving synchronously then that means your page will end up 'waiting' for every chart to load except these last two which come after the last getHTML invocations.


        drawChart('column', 'monthly-orders-chart', '/om/chart-data/monthly_om_totals.php', '', '');
        drawChart('column', 'monthly-ar-chart', '/ar/chart-data/monthly_ar_totals.php', '', '');

Is your whole website dependent on these getHtml functions?

Comment: If you comment them out, does your code still behave synchronously? Knowing that will help narrow down.